# accessing codeigniter session values in another codeigniter installation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two Codeigniter installation on my wamp. I want to use one Codeigniter session values in another Codeigniter installation.

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 include('index.php');
 ob_end_clean();
 $CI =& get_instance();
 $CI->load->library('session'); 
 echo $CI->session->userdata('name');
 ?>
```

I have seen this code on stackoverflow. How do i use it?? Can anyone tell me about this??
Anyone tried this??

Comment: why you want do this?

Comment: it's my project requirement...

Comment: If both applications are hosted on same domain name, session sharing shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you host both your web sites/web applications on same domain then its possible to get session values from one website to another web site.above code is enough to get session values.